# Return Ivoke message DialogResult

Tags: c#, multithreading

All.
I have made a generalized static method to use by other forms.
now i wanted to return that message box result how can i?

I am using code as :-

```
public static DialogResult ShowMessage(Form Parent, string Text, string Caption, MessageBoxButtons Buttons, MessageBoxIcon Icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton DefaultButton)
    {
        if (Parent != null && Parent.InvokeRequired)
            return (DialogResult) Parent.Invoke((Action)(() => MessageBox.Show(Text, Caption, Buttons, Icon, DefaultButton)));
        else
            return (MessageBox.Show(Text, Caption, Buttons, Icon, DefaultButton));
    }
```

It throws Object reference error with simple message box (e.g. Ok message).
Null reference comes after showing the message.

Comment: That needs to be a `Func<DialogResult>`, not an Action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Action` doesn't have return value, you should use `Func` instead:

```
return (DialogResult) Parent.Invoke(new Func<DialogResult>(() =>
 { return MessageBox.Show(Text, Caption, Buttons, Icon, DefaultButton); }));
```

BTW, if you don't want to repeat same code (`MessageBox.Show(...)`) twice, you can use delegates in the following way:

```
delegate DialogResult MyInvoke(Form Parent, string Text, string Caption, MessageBoxButtons Buttons, MessageBoxIcon Icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton DefaultButton);

public static DialogResult ShowMessage(Form Parent, string Text, string Caption, MessageBoxButtons Buttons, MessageBoxIcon Icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton DefaultButton)
{
    if (Parent.InvokeRequired){
        return (DialogResult)Parent.Invoke(new MyInvoke(ShowMessage), Parent, Text, Caption, Buttons, Icon, DefaultButton);
    }
    return MessageBox.Show(Text, Caption, Buttons, Icon, DefaultButton);
}
```